# Как сделать плавную анимацию отрисовки, точнее как овладеть двойной буферизацией?

Tags: c#, winforms, графика

Как сделать плавную анимацию отрисовки, точнее как овладеть двойной буферизацией:

- Как инициализировать такую графику?
- Как отрисовывать?

Инициализация формы:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    graphics = panel1.CreateGraphics(); //графика  
    timer1.Start(); //таймер с интервалом 1   
    picture = new Picture(panel1); //в picture список объектов на отрисовку  
}
```

Отрисовка:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{   
    graphics.Clear(Color.White);  
    picture.Draw(graphics);  
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, ваш заголовок не отражает суть вопроса, исправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать либо читали о двойной буферизации?

Comment: Покажите пример кода, в котором у вас происходит неплавная анимация.

Answer (score 1):

Наилучший результат в большинстве случаев дает следующий способ:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //какие-то переменные для хранения состояния...
    int x = 0;        
    string FullName = @"C:\Media\test.jpg";
    Bitmap image;

    //включение двойной буферизации на уровне окна
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  

        //логика инициализации        
        image = new Bitmap(FullName); 
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //логика изменения картинки (период таймера: 50 - 100 мс)
        x += 1;
        if (x > 100) x = 0;

        panel1.Refresh(); //обновление Panel             
    }        

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //логика отрисовки
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, x, 0);

    }
}
```

Если этот способ не дает желаемого результата в вашем случае, попробуйте что-то из описанного здесь: [Windows Forms - Using Double Buffering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-double-buffering)